# Space between label and input

Tags: html, css

I have multiple input/textarea with some label. What I want is to make a space between label and input it self. Problem is that label text is different always

For example:

```
<p class="formfield">
    <label translate="case.calculation.label.price"></label>
    <input ng-model="part.priceByUser" class="table-form">
</p>
<p class="formfield">
    <label for="textarea" translate="case.calculation.parts.description"></label>
    <textarea id="textarea" rows="3" ng-model="part.descriptionByUser" class="table-form"></textarea>
</p>
```

Looks like:

[image]

I think this may be done with fixed label width, so i added something like:

```
.formfield label {
    padding-right:10px;
    width: 15%;
}
```

With what it looks correct on all normal screen e.g.:
[image]

But have problem on small device as mobile phones where label text can overflow below input area e.g.:

[image]

I will be happy for any advise or best practice for this kind of issue :)
Thanks guys.

Comment: Add fixed width to `min-width` css property.

Comment: Flexbox or table-cell will help you. If you set `display` to `table` (parent) and `table-cell`(for childrens) all columns will be rearranged automatically

Comment: I would just set the label and input width as 100% on smaller devices with media queries.

Comment: use bootstrap styles are already responsive

Comment: Thank you all for answers, Mr_Green min-width will not overflow on small device but will looks same as first example above.  Marco I would like to skip using tables, I have really bad exp with it.  @thepio i will be happy for example because it looks really as a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we talked about using media queries in the comments (and you did ask for best practises) of your answer. I'm not saying this always is the best practise but would work in your situation and leaves a lot of space for the label and the input which is generally a good practise in mobile. A simple way to possibly do some changes to your labels would be to use css like this:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

  .formfield label {
    padding-right:0px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .formfield input, .formfield textarea {
    width: 100%;
  }

}
```

Please consider all of your other css may be different from mine but in your example this would probably work great. Just set the `480px` to what ever suites your needs the best. It's the breakpoint when the media query takes affect.

Just for reference: [MDN - Using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, you must set fixed label width (`15%` is NOT fixed width). I also would use table layout for better looks:

```css
.formfield {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.formfield label,
.formfield .input-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.formfield label {
  width: 100px;
}
.formfield .input-wrapper .table-form {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="formfield">
  <label for="price">Price</label>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input id="price" class="table-form" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="formfield">
  <label for="textarea">Description</label>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <textarea id="textarea" rows="3" class="table-form"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already know the maximum space taking by a label then apply that space's value as `min-width` to all labels. Something like this:

```
.formfield label {
    padding-right:10px;
    width: 15%;        /* to maintain responsive */
    min-width: 120px;  /* minimum threshold width */
}
```

This makes sure that the minimum width of the labels are not less than `120px` even when `15%` of the width is less than `120px`. Hence, the layout will be still responsive.